# How can I redirect virtualhosts (different domain) on the same port (443) to different internal ports?

Tags: docker

I understand I can redirect HTTP traffic using Nginx.

But what about non-HTTP traffic, Such as SSHD, etc? I'm asking because I have various dockerized services that will like to share the parent server's 443 port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protocols in which the first message being send is from the client to the server, and where that message contains the hostname can trivially be proxied based on hostname.

That includes HTTP with Host header (the host Header was optional in HTTP/1.0 and is mandatory in HTTP/1.1), as well as HTTPS as long as the client supports SNI.

In practice this means it will work for all HTTP clients and most of the HTTPS clients not running outdated software.

Notice that SSH is not one of those protocols, and it also doesn't run on port 443. The SSH protocol doesn't send a hostname (the protocol has no need for the hostname, not even in the encrypted messages). But that's not the only reason it is impossible to proxy SSH based on hostname:

- Hostname is not passed in the protocol
- Server sends its first message before anything has been received from the client
- A proxy cannot modify any part of the messages being sent because even the initial unencrypted part of communication is verified with a signature shortly after encryption has been set up.

Any proxying of SSH to multiple backends require a modification of the protocol or encapsulating SSH inside another protocol to bypass the issue.

Answer (score 0):

sshd runs on tcp/22. This has nothing to do with tcp/443. This has also nothing with nginx, since it currently cannot handle ssh (hopefully it won't be able in the distant future too).